# Who is the culprit of all this Prapancha when I was, is and shall continue to be ONE?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta

Who was responsible or what was responsible for making me forget who I am? How did this Universe start when there were no two? How did I separate myself from myself and create this Prapancha?

Comment: Did it start/ Is there zero reality to Prapancha?

Comment: This reality is Brahman which means "one that expands". So, at one point there was nothing in the beginning but single Self, hence the universe/Brahman expanded from inside to outside.                              
                                                                                                                "In the beginning this was Self alone, in the shape of a person (puruṣa). He looking around saw nothing but his Self (Atman). He first said, "This is I", therefore he became I by name."
—Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.1

Comment: Therefore crux of Yoga and Vedanta is to understand inside, the real seer. All the outside(senses and matter) is created to point inside. You did not forget it, you are ignoring it because of addiction to temporary sensual pleasures.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_Jiva_and_Atman

Renounce every temporary thing through Neti-Neti(not this, not this) and you will find yourself. Bhagavad Gita 9.4 This entire cosmic manifestation is pervaded by Me in My unmanifest form. All living beings dwell in Me, but I do not dwell in them.

Comment: Bacteria, in maya Lokas, 99% of beings are bacteria, evil spirits who imposterise people in your memory.

Answer (score 1):

From own experience, Black magic, Bacteria, in maya Lokas, 99% of beings are bacteria, microbes, evil spirits who can spaceshift, appear anywhere, they can even mess your memories, create false memories, as well as dreams get registered as such, do anything they want, imposterise people in your memory, although their faces might look little or very different, when you become racially pure, void of any impure bacteria, microbe etc inside body, dna, you realise that you're soul, brahman, and not that egoistic greedy selfish leecher bacteria, which after eating food you feed to it, thinking you're feeding your stomach, while in reality those bacteria eat it, even biology states that indirectly, biology is about bacteria, projected as good, villain vs Jewish Allopathy itself presented as hero, just like all Jewish institutions trying to pretend to solve problems, present themselves as good, while they themselves have created deliberately problems in first place secretly, give delusion of hunger, tiredness, per their whims, sends back waste, thoughts are bacteria making, activate brain areas fire randomly, very similar to Parallel UNIVERSE, Here are some signs of parallel universes, someone you know won't wear clothes they always used to wear before(those clothes might not even exist in parallel universe), some place you always used to visit earlier (imprint from that universe) closed down abruptly after your last visit. Unless you're turiya, you might be constantly shifting between parallel universes, sleeping, then waking up is gateway to travel to other universes, As well as negative things like butterfly effect, happen, for example when I was black magicED that year bloody Obama became president of US, Maya loka is equal to dream or virtual reality, and after I started to break out this maya, in 2016,trump righteously became president, as well as before observation, a thing can coexist in all possible states, there's uncertainty to know for sure what's real, what's not, but only when observed it becomes fixed on one, , based on our chakra, Karma, but one where you don't have control on events, anything or anyone. Our consciousness and its contents make our reality, If you close your eyes while doing any yoga, sadhana, nadi shuddi, etc, attain turiya, then you come back to brahmaloka(similar to travelling beyond black hole event horizon, ending up in another universe, that's how you get dreams as well), the only real universe, if you don't close your eyes, dimension won't shift, even if you attain turiya. Chakras are black hole/wormhole like entrances to other dimensions(Lokas). As well as different people live in different realities, Lokas. There's no thing as objective experience or truth, because everything is relative to the observer, Seer, experiencing.

Comment: I think it is better to give para breaks occasionally for increasing the readability.   Further,  this site requires quoting of references.  Please check. @Aoi.T_015

Comment: reference? Bacteria theory is something new to me.

Comment: What did I just read 